# Check how many references are held to a given instance in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, reference, weak-references

Is it possible to check how many references are held to a given instance in .NET 3.5?

Comment: OldNewThing has a post about this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/11/10048629.aspx

Comment: Can you explain what you need that for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get this information at runtime via the CLR as reference counts are not maintained by the CLR. A big hint of this is that the Garbage Collector is generational and not reference count driven.

Raymond Chen has a good post on this topic here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/11/10048629.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the WinDbg debugger if you load the SOS extension:

```
.loadby sos.dll mscorwks
```

You'll need to find the address of the object in memory, probably best done using the `!dumpheap` command. With the object address, you can then run `!gcroot <address>` to find all the references to your object.

Answer (score 1):

While debugging, You can use Windbg to get this data. There are specific commands in Windbg. I am not an expert in Windbg but this would get you started

http://www.bytetalk.net/2009/03/windbg-tips-and-tricks.html

Answer (score 1):

I love ANTS Memory Profiler for those kind of tasks.